# QuickPDF Instance Creation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, pdf

I am unable to create an instance using PDFLibrary in C#.

The dll lives at c:/the project directory/lib/DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.dll

I generate the path and also tried hard coding it.

```
var dllPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Lib\\DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.dll";
```

This method assumes SysWOW or System32 dirs.

```
PDFLibrary QP = new PDFLibrary("DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.dll");
```

Also attempted with this:

```
PDFLibrary QP = new PDFLibrary(dllPath);
```

I've included the import file: DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.cs
Inside the constructor, dll.dllHandle is always 0. The object is never instantiated. 
This is the part inside the DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.cs file that creates the dll instance.

```
    public PDFLibrary(string dllFileName)
    {
        dll = new DLL(dllFileName);
        if (dll.dllHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            instanceID = dll.DebenuPDFLibraryCreateLibrary();
            dll.RegisterForShutdown(instanceID);
        }
        else
        {
            dll = null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this would happen aside from having the wrong location of the dll? I have uninstalled / reinstalled the quick pdf data a few times.

Based on their documentation it should live in the SysWOW or System32 folders based on your application needs.

I think the issue is the dll and the server has the site set to the incorrect application type. I will try to change that next.

Comment: can you actually show all relevant code.. ? where is dllFileName declared / defined..? also can you confirm the folder structure of where you have Lib residing is it in the `bin\debug` folder..?

Comment: c:/the project directory/lib/DebenuPDFLibraryDLL1016.dll
It also lives in the SysWOW and System32 folders.

Comment: `c:\ or c:/` there is a difference between a backslash`\` think falling backwards and a forward slash `/` think falling forward.. lol do you get any errors also can you look at the object browser for `PDFLibrary` and see it's methods and method signature for the constructors..?

Comment: have you looked at this site if this is the product you are using http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/getting-started/getting-started-dll-edition/

Comment: also where are you declaring `instanceID` it doesn't appear that you have read any of the documentation I am curious as to if you are getting compiler errors when you compile this

Comment: I've read the documentation and posted in their forum. I fixed the issue. It is because the server didn't have the application setup to use the DLL I was trying to use. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me include my comment here as it seems I'm being told I didn't read the docs.

I've read the documentation and posted in their forum.

I fixed the issue. It is because the server didn't have the application setup to use the DLL I was trying to use. It's a 32 bit DLL and the server is 64 bit. I wasn't informed of this until a few minutes ago. Once I changed the reference for the DLL to the 64 bit version, it worked.

Comment: thank you for posting your own solution, saved me a great deal of time and headache